# Product of two Tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to multiply two tensors namely fx and px. but it gives this error (`InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Mul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a float tensor but is a double tensor [Op:Mul]`). The code is as follows

```
x_l = -2.0
x_h = 4.0

h = (x_h - x_l) / M

x = np.arange(x_l, x_h, h)
def fn(x):
  f = 0.2 - x + ((x ** 8) / (1 + (x ** 8)))
  return f


p_x = tf.keras.Sequential([
                         tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_nodes_hl1_g1,activation='tanh',input_shape=(1,1)),
                         tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_nodes_hl2_g1,activation='tanh'),
                         #tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_nodes_hl3_g1,activation='tanh'),
                         tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes) 
                        ])

optimizer_p_x = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learn_rate)

x_tensor = tf.Variable(x.reshape(-1, x.shape[0], 1))

fx = fn(x_tensor)
px = p_x(x_tensor)

prod = tf.math.multiply(px, fx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy arrays get interpreted as double tensors by tensorflow. In your case specifying that `x_tensor` is of dtype `tf.float32` is sufficient.

```
x_tensor = tf.Variable(x.reshape(-1, x.shape[0], 1), dtype=tf.float32)
```